# How to log the actual request header when using fetch API

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, service-worker

Beginner question, I am using the fetch API in one of my Cloudflare Service Worker to send request to a third party; Everything works fine that I am able to send out the request and receive response; But now I have a need to log everything I sent and received, which I am not sure how exactly can I do so;

**The main requirement:**
**Able to log the whole request header being sent**

The problem is that the request header that I specified is not the full header being sent, like in the following example I only specified the content-type, but in real practice it will send with more properties added by the application itself, e.g. accept, x-forwarded-for, content-length, etc.

Request:

```
    var toThirdPartyReqMethod = 'POST';
    var toThirdPartyReqHeader = {'content-type': 'application/json'};    
    var toThirdPartyReqSetting = {
      method: toThirdPartyReqMethod,
      headers: toThirdPartyReqHeader,
      body: toThirdPartyReqBodyArrayBuffer
    };
    var toThirdPartyUrl = "https://somewhere.com";

    var fromThirdPartyResponse = await fetch(toThirdPartyUrl, toThirdPartyReqSetting)

    var fromThirdPartyResponseBodyArrayBuffer = await fromThirdPartyResponse.arrayBuffer();
```

I am able to use fromThirdPartyResponse to digest the response; but I have no idea how to record the exact request I sent out.

I tried to do it as follows:

```
var oriReqHeaderContentType = fromThirdPartyResponse.request.headers.get("content-type");
```

But obviously it is not the right answer and returned with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Anyone gets some idea of how to log the request being sent when using fetch API?

Sorry for asking beginner questions :(

Comment: Are you trying to access the request headers from your frontend JavaScript code running in the browser? If so, the answer is that you can’t — the browser adds request headers of its own, after your frontend JavaScript code runs. So there’s no way you can access the complete set of request headers from your frontend JavaScript code. The only request headers you can access are the ones you explicitly set yourself in your own frontend code. Your otherwise have no way of programatically determining what other headers your browser might be including in the request it sends out.

Answer (score -1):

You can access request headers like this

const contentType = req.get("Content-Type");

Comment: Yes I knew about this too; but how to do the same thing when using fetch()? I only know how to use fetch by this var resp = await fetch(url, req); 

Problem is that I cannot use req simply because some request header is being added by Cloudflare Service Worker itself that I didn't specify, e.g. cf-visitor, cf-ew-via and so on